# Anaconda Jupyter shows eroor when importing tensorflow

Tags: python, anaconda

I am having the following error when importing TensorFlow:

> ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
>       Below is the traceback from this internal error.

I believe it is related to .dll

> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

I am using Python version `3.7.4`.

Any advice? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

$ conda install tensorflow==2.0.0